# Solution to the Partial Differential Equation $ u_t - xtu_x = 0 $

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the partial differential equation $$ u_t - xtu_x = 0 $$ with the initial condition $$ u(x, 0) = \sin(x) $$. I have gone through the following steps and would like to confirm if they are correct.

From the partial differential equation $$ u_t - xtu_x = 0 $$, I obtained the characteristic equations:
$$ \frac{dt}{1} = \frac{dx}{-xt}  $$

Upon integration, I get:
$$ \ln|x| = -\frac{t^2}{2} + c $$
where $c$ is another integration constant.

Since $ \frac{du}{0} $, I know that $ u $is constant along the characteristic curve. Therefore, the general solution can be represented as:
$$ u(x, t) = f\left(e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}x\right) $$
where $ f $ is an arbitrary function.

Therefore, the particular solution is:
$$ u(x, t) = \sin\left(e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}x\right) $$

Is my solution correct? If not, where did I go wrong and how can I correct it?

Comment: You can test if your solution is correct by checking if it satisfies the desired PDE.